# winJs Listview Item Template of variable or auto Height

Tags: microsoft-metro, winjs

Hi I am creating a list view and the winJs template for the list view although I do `auto` to its height it some whats takes the height of the Largest possible Element. Is it Not possible to Keep a variable Height Listview. Please let me know if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the solution is to use `listview.onloadingstatechanged` event.

Where you can modify your listview when `loadingState` changes to `completed`

But That wont yeild a very good result. The only work around is to use `<div></div` in order to get a scroll able container. More over listview's load upto a specified number of characters So applying loading state changed and styling in it will become quite messy.

Let me know when you have tried it.

Here's a link to the event
[Loading State changed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700709.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

By default, the ListView allocates the same size for each item in the list. When you use a grid layout, you can modify this behavior and display items that are different sizes by making the items span multiple cells.  and The size of the cell is determined by the size of the first item in the ListView. When the ListView contains items of different sizes, it still allocates the cell size based on the size of the first item. So, if one item is larger than the others, it will be clipped to match the sizes of the other ListView items.

bellow link may help you

http://www.ourgoalplan.com/KLMS/TipView.aspx?id=3474

Comment: Link is not accessible

Comment: oh I am surprised that,how the link is not accessible

Comment: It asks for a login to some klms site. Never had an account before.